# Class loading collision between Robolectric and Powermock

Tags: powermock, robolectric

I'm trying to write a test that needs both **Robolectric** 2.2 and **PowerMock**, as the code under test depends on some Android libraries and third party libraries with final classes that I need to mock.

Given that I'm forced to use the Robolectric test runner through:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
```

...I cannot use the PowerMock test runner, so I'm trying to go with the PowerMock java agent alternative, without luck so far.

I have setup everything according to [this guide](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockAgent) but I'm facing a collision problem between classes required by the javaagent library and by robolectric through its dependency with asm-1.4. Both depend on

> org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor

, but javaagent-1.5.1 ships with its own version where ClassVisitor is an interface while asm-1.4 version for the same namespace is an abstract class, with the corresponding error at runtime:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

I have even tried to modify the javaagent library jar to entirely remove the org.objectew.asm classes in there, but that doesn't work as ClassNotFoundException happens afterwards due to some other classes needed in the org.objectweb.asm package that only ship in the javaagent library jar, and not in the asm one.

Any ideas? According to examples out there the agent seems to work fine with, at least, the Spring test runner.

Comment: This is most likely not the answer you want, but you could switch to Mockito.  I'm positive that it plays nice with Robolectric.

Comment: Hi @ErichDouglass. I also use Mockito as part of my toolset, but I want to use PowerMock in order to mock final classes from 3rd party libraries that are dependencies of my tested code.

Comment: Same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20557769/16487).  I'll mark as dup if you ever get an answer.  Defect logged [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=470&q=robolectric).

Comment: I've used JMockIt with much success to mock final classes from 3rd party libraries

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and while I didn't solve this problem as such, I wanted to share my approach, which removes the need for PowerMock (which is always a good thing in my view): I wanted to mock a call to

```
Fragment fooFragment = new FooFragment();
```

So what I did was addanother level of indirection. I created a FragmentProvider class:

```
public FragmentFactory fragmentFactory = new FragmentFactory();
[...]
Fragment fooFragment = fragmentFactory.getFooFragment();
```

After i did this, I could just mock out the factory with standard Mockito, like this:

```
FragmentFactory mockFactory = mock(FragmentFactory.class);
activity.fragmentFactory = mockFactory;
when(mockFactory.getFooFragment()).thenReturn(mockFooFragment);
```