# Using PowerMock and Robolectric - IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, android, powermock, robolectric

I'm trying to use PowerMockito to mock some static methods in Android Robolectric tests.  I'm using JUnit 4.8.2, Robolectric 2.2, Mockito 1.9.5, and PowerMock 1.9.5 as directed [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13).  As I have to use the [RoboElectricTestRunner](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/RobolectricTestRunner.html), I'm attempting to use the [PowerMockRule](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule) to bootstrap PowerMock.  However I'm getting an unfortunate `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError` when the test with PowerMock runs.

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:323)
>   at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:348)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637) 
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621) 
>   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)

If I put `org.ow2.asm` after the `org.powermock` libraries I get:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
>   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

on *every* unit test.

According to Maven depency:tree Robolectric and PowerMock don't share any dependencies. **But** apparently **org.powermock:powermock-module-javaagent** packages some **org/objectweb/asm** classes, and Robolectric relies on **org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.1** causing a conflict.

---

```java
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Helper.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.jmx.*", "javax.management.*"})
public class HelpFragTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    static {
        PowerMockAgent.initializeIfNeeded();
    }

    FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    ActionBarManager actionBarManager;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        actionBarManager = mock(ActionBarManager.class);
        LowesApplication.instance().setActionBarManager(actionBarManager);
        fragmentActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();
        fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    @Test
    public void testShow(){
        mockStatic(Helper.class);

        HelpFrag helpFrag = HelpFrag.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(helpFrag, null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        assertTrue(helpFrag.isVisible());
    }
}
```

Comment: To use power mock you have to run it with power mock runner. So when you try to run it with Robolectric test runner it doesn't have sense

Comment: @EugenMartynov That's the problem the javaagent and `PowerMockRule` are supposed to be solving, see [PowerMockRule](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule) and [PowerMockAgent](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockAgent).

Comment: Cool, let me know if you solve it since this is also problem for us

Comment: @EugenMartynov I'll post it here if I figure it out.

Comment: @EugenMartynov There's [another StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19998398/16487) and an [Issue Logged](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=470&q=robolectric).  Looks like a problem with the source.

Comment: @C.Ross What is the status of this?

Answer (score 10):

I found a way to use PowerMock in conjunction with Robolectric.

In addition to the standard PowerMock jars, the PowerMock Junit Rule is also needed. It is described [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule) how to grab it. I used the `xstream` classloading version, because the `objenesis` one is very buggy. This is working with PowerMock 1.5.5 and Robolectric 2.3, i cannot speak about the older versions. Also please note that the Java agent should not be included, because from my experience it causes problems.

So if you are using maven, these dependencies should be declared:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you have to setup your test class like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*" })
@PrepareForTest(Static.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    private MyActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).create().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);
        Mockito.when(Static.getCurrentTime()).thenReturn(1);

        Assert.assertEquals(1, activity.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: I worked with this method some, it was posted in the related Android issue, and I had fits with things conflicting between the Robolectric classloader and Powermock classloader.

Comment: Note that Robolectric might not be loading in the shadows correctly, this is something I'm currently experiencing with this setup